# There’s a more permanent way to sign in to Microsoft Teams. If you’re having trouble completing the process, talk to your IT admin

Tags: microsoft-teams

I installed Teams on my desktop. When ever I click it, the error message in my screenshot springs up. Why?

Here's my stopgap that wastes too much time. I must open my Outlook For Business, find any email from someone else containing a Teams link, and click it. Then Teams opens successfully.

This wastes time because if I am merely opening Teams to call my Contact to chat like Skype, I don't need any Teams links or access my Outlook For Business! Like Skype I should need just click on Teams on desktop to load Teams, sign in, and call.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/XJvhXbh.png]

### My neighbor apprised me how to solve this glitch, but he can't explain it.

Just [clear cache as outlined by Veejay RC](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/clear-cache/0810ce4f-af14-4269-b01f-adc89a0af4c4). But neighbor doesn't know why clearing cache solves. Then my glitch disappeared! Yay!

> To clear your Teams desktop app cache:
> 1. Sign out on Teams > Quit Microsoft Teams by right clicking the icon and select Quit.
> 2. On your keyboard, Hold Windows key and Press R
> 3. Cut and paste %appdata%\Microsoft\Teams in the RUN then OK.
> 4. Delete the contents of the entire folder.
> 5. Restart Device > Restart Microsoft Teams > Sign In.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if you launch Teams using the desktop or start menu shortcut, you arrive at the error message in the screenshot, is that correct? Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling yet?

Comment: Is this business accounts? Do you have an IT dept and have you asked them?